# Quitting during probation after 4 months - need advice

Tags: resignation, probation

I am in my late 20s and started a mid senior level role in supply chain in May. It's been a really bad fit for me. The culture of the company is ultra competitive, I don't get any guidance from my manager, it's a sink or swim environment. Also, I simply don't like the work I am doing. I feel I have been under performing even though I have not gotten in trouble yet.

I interviewed with a company which I really like and feel it would be a better fit for me. I am really close in getting an offer. My probationary period is 6 months long. I would like to accept the offer if I receive an offer but I am really scared of leaving after 4 months. I am afraid my managers will be really upset at me?

Has anyone else been in this situation before? Any advice?

Comment: Your'e lucky that you are still young and probably can handle the stress well of such a situation. My last two jobs were similar to this and the stress of having no support and a high workload was immense. I agree with what the other respondents have said, but will emphasise one thing, you really need for the next job to work out, so if you have gone from the frying pan into the fire, you will have to work real hard so you don't end up leaving two jobs in a row in a short time frame

Comment: Do these managers have particular influence in your industry in your locale?

Comment: Can you clarify what your goal is? Are you asking how to quit without upsetting your managers? Are you asking if quitting is somehow unprofessional?

Answer (score 19):

The probation period is there for exactly this purpose. It's not just for you to prove yourself to the company, but also for the company to prove themselves to you. If it's not working out, walk away.

Behave with dignity, but I'm afraid there's no way to guarantee your old managers will or won't react in any particular way. Well, will you stay in a job that isn't right for you for the next five years to avoid the risk of upsetting someone else - someone who hasn't offered you the guidance and support you wanted?

Simply ask to speak to your manager, hand over your resignation letter, and say something like "I'm sorry, I know I've not been here for long, but I just feel like it's not working out". (The "sorry" part is only social convention, you're not doing anything wrong you should really need to apologise for, but it helps to mitigate any potential bad feelings. And by talking about how you feel, nobody can say you are wrong - "I feel it's not a good fit for me" can't be disputed, "you didn't give me any support" could be).

Comment: Thank you. The company i am at right now is known to be really cut throat and competitive. However, I still feel guilty if i take the offer to leave my team behind

Comment: @VanillaIce1992, such companies are used to regular turnover of staff. I wouldn't feel guilty.

Comment: Yeah there is a lot of turnover but i i still feel guilty neverthless

Comment: @VanillaIce1992 don't feel guilty, they'd let you go in a heartbeat if it was better for them.

Answer (score 2):

At this point I assume the other company knows that you have been with your current employer and your current rationale for leaving?

If you believe that your situation will not negatively affect your employment chance I would not care.

If your current employer has that kind of work attitude they should be used to people leaving often and should not be too surprised given the details that you provided.

Just do what's best for yourself.